# Script/Tool to convert C source code encoded by "xxd -i" to C source code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, xxd

Is there a Linux/Unix tool that can be used to convert the hex dump array of a C file (i.e. the output of `xxd -i`) to the corresponding source code?

Comment: Do you mean a disassembler ? Or perhaps reverse engineering ?

Comment: I think you want a decompiler.

Comment: I think this question makes since if  you mean back to binary, not src code. As Jonathan answer's. In this way it seems xxd is lacking in giving a format it can't reverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `xxd -i xyz.c` for a source file `xyz.c` looks like:

```
unsigned char xyz_c[] = {
  0x23, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x74,
  0x64, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x2e, 0x68, 0x3e, 0x0a, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x6c,
  0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x73, 0x74, 0x64, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x62, 0x2e,
  0x68, 0x3e, 0x0a, 0x23, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x2e, 0x68, 0x3e, 0x0a, 0x0a,
  …
  0x65, 0x5f, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x28, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x74,
  0x29, 0x3b, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x7d, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 0x74, 0x75, 0x72, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x30, 0x3b, 0x0a,
  0x7d, 0x0a
};
unsigned int xyz_c_len = 4442;
```

Assume that is stored in a file `xyz.xxd`.

In many ways, the easiest way to regenerate the original code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xyz.xxd"

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < xyz_c_len; i++)
        putchar(xyz_c[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

With some more care and some macros, you could make that a general-purpose outline program for the job — you'd need to supply the file name, and the two C variable names to be used.

If you can't (or don't want to) use a C compiler for the job, then writing a tool using Python or Perl is a straight-forward exercise.  For example, a not necessarily minimal Perl script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -na
use strict;
use warnings;

# xxd -i drops the final comma - aargh (why?)!
foreach my $word (@F)
{
    next unless $word =~ m/^0[Xx][[:xdigit:]]{2},?$/;
    $word =~ s/,//;
    printf "%c", hex($word);
}
```

It uses the 'auto-split' option (`-a`) and 'automatic read but do not print' option (`-n`), and then processes any words in the input that look like a hex character, such as 0x0a (optionally followed by a comma since `xxd -i` somewhat unnecessarily omits the comma after the final byte value) and converts that to the corresponding byte.  It being Perl, TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It.

Answer (score 1):

The [Boomerang Decompiler](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) is free, works on Linux, and is available on SourceForge.